# Counting pairs where one element is the same, but the other differs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a long list of pairs (user, organisation), alongside other columns. I only want to see the pairs with the same user, but different organisation.

| User | Organisation | Other Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | example1_1 |
| 2 | 1 | example2_1 |
| 3 | 1 | example3_1 |
| 3 | 1 | example3_1 |
| 3 | 2 | example3_2 |
| 3 | 1 | example3_1 |
| 4 | 1 | example4_1 |
| 4 | 2 | example4_2 |
| 4 | 3 | example4_3 |
| 4 | 1 | example4_1 |

My attempt with a ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ...), was to just have a flag greater than 1 where these records have the same user ID but a different organisation ID. But I cannot make it to increment on different organisation IDs, it counts when the organisation ID is the same instead. The desired result is:

| User | Organisation | Other Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | example3_1 |
| 3 | 2 | example3_2 |
| 4 | 1 | example4_1 |
| 4 | 2 | example4_2 |
| 4 | 3 | example4_3 |

Would someone please be able to generalise it so that I can partition on a fixed number of elements, so that some of my choice stay fixed and others vary?

Comment: Let's say the `OtherData` could be different within multiple rows for the same User and Organization. How do you want to decide which value(s) to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More nesting than I like, but this will do it:

```
SELECT [User], Organization, OtherData
FROM (
    select uo.*, row_number() over (partition by uo.[User], Organization order by OtherData) rn
    from UserOrgs uo
    where exists( 
        SELECT 1
        FROM [UserOrgs] uo0
        WHERE uo0.[User] = uo.[User]
        GROUP BY uo0.[User]
        HAVING COUNT(Organization) > 1
    ) 
) w -- window
WHERE rn = 1
```

See it (and two other options) work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/vjJX9YX4

If there is more than one row for a given `(User,Organization)` pair, you can control which exact row is used for `OtherData` by changing the `order by` expression in the `row_number()` window.

It's also worth mentioning that if `OtherData` is a stand-in for multiple columns, this method will ensure all the columns shown in a result row come from the *same source row*. It is possible to craft a solution (shown in the link) using `GROUP BY` and an aggregate function for each additional column, in place of the `row_number()` layer. It removes a layer of nesting, which is nice, but it does not make this "same row" guarantee.

---

##### A note on the use of ALL CAPS for code in this answer.

SQL has a long-standing tradition (that seems to be fading) of using ALL CAPS for keywords. I have my own adaption of this. When nesting queries, I will alternate capitalization between nesting levels, to help make it obvious what level I'm looking at for a given expression. This is why the middle level is all lower-case, but the inner and outer levels use CAPS.

It never used to matter, but with the advent of window functions I've found a lot of queries have an extra level of nesting just to filter on a window result, and so it's been helpful in recent years. If SQL Server ever gets the `QUALIFY` keyword this might no longer be as useful.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example data:

```
create table #pairs
(
    [User] int,
    Organisation int,
    [Other Data] varchar(20)
)

insert into #pairs values
(1,1,'example1_1'),
(2,1,'example2_1'),
(3,1,'example3_1'),
(3,1,'example3_1'),
(3,2,'example3_2'),
(3,1,'example3_1'),
(4,1,'example4_1'),
(4,2,'example4_2'),
(4,3,'example4_3'),
(4,1,'example4_1')
```

This query gets your desired results:

```
select distinct
    [User],
    Organisation,
    [Other Data]
from #pairs
where [User] in
(
    select [User]
    from #pairs
    group by [User]
    having count(distinct Organisation) > 1
)
```

Results:

| User | Organisation | Other Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | example3_1 |
| 3 | 2 | example3_2 |
| 4 | 1 | example4_1 |
| 4 | 2 | example4_2 |
| 4 | 3 | example4_3 |

However, this assumes that for a given pair of `User` and `Organisation` values, there will only be one distinct `Other Data` value. If this is not the case, you need to update your question to explain how you want to determine which `Other Data` value to return.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem here is that I cannot get any of the other columns, as it throws the classic aggregate error. Can you please adjust the answer so that I can return all the other data? This is why I was trying to partition, with no success.

Comment: @SamuelHyde What other columns? Your question doesn't tell anything about that. Please edit it and add all necessary information.

Comment: I did mention in the first line that I have other columns in the table as well, I should have probably been clearer. I have adjusted the example now.

Comment: Are the values in the `Other Data` column always the same between multiple instances of the same pairs or `User` and `Organisation` values? So will `Other Data` always be "example3_1" when `User` is 3 and `Organisation` is 1? If these `Other Data` values could vary between these records, how do you want to decide which `Other Data` value to return?